# Recursively process JSON array to find common values across all object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, recursion

I have been very much struggling to recursively process this JSON structure over the last few days and am hoping someone can assist me.

I have an array which contains multiple JSON objects. Each object represents a question and has 1 or more possible answers. Each answer contains 1 or more possible conditions which in turn contain 1 datapoint and 1 requiredValue.

**JSON object**

```
[
  {
    "originalQ": "Have you been to hospital?",
    "originalA": "No",
    "potentialAnswers": [
      {
        "conditions": [
          {
            "datapoint": "Hospitalization",
            "assoicatedValue": "more than 2 years ago "
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "conditions": [
          {
            "datapoint": "Hospitalization",
            "assoicatedValue": "never"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "originalQ": "Has a medical professional diagnosed you?",
    "originalA": "No",
    "potentialAnswers": [
      {
        "conditions": [
          {
            "datapoint": "OtherDiagnosis",
            "assoicatedValue": "has never"
          },
          {
            "datapoint": "Hospitalization",
            "assoicatedValue": "never"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "originalQ": "Are you taking medication?",
    "originalA": "Yes",
    "potentialAnswers": [
      {
        "conditions": [
          {
            "datapoint": "Medications",
            "assoicatedValue": "1-3"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "conditions": [
          {
            "datapoint": "Medications",
            "assoicatedValue": "4 or more"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "originalQ": "How many different medications do you take?",
    "originalA": "4 or more",
    "potentialAnswers": [
      {
        "conditions": [
          {
            "datapoint": "Medications",
            "assoicatedValue": "4 or more"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**I need to get a JSON object that contains datapoint:assoicatedValue pairs that would allow us to find one matching element in each question potentialAnswer array for each question object.**

There will always be fewer datapoints than answers so I need to know what value I can assign each datapoint in order to have 1 valid object in the potentialAnswer array for each question. If there are no such possible combination I need to be alerted to that.

Ultimately each datapoint can only have one value so whatever values they are assigned cannot conflict with the answers for other questions. This would be considered an overall object answer.

**Some addition info:**

1. Every is dynamically generated i.e. datapoint names can change between runs (but consistent across objects for same run), number of question objects changes.
2. There are some cases where it will not be possible to find datapoint values and it such cases the function should return that info.

Outcome below matches at least one potential answer in each question.

**Required Outcome**

```
{
  "Hospitalization": "never ",
  "OtherDiagnosis": "has never",
  "Medications": "4 or more"
}
```

I have tried a number of approaches to this but always run into an issue I cannot solve. The code below is the closest I've gotten. It works in most cases but seems to have issues if it encounters an issue in the last question object.

**Code Attempt**

```
let allQuestionData = require('./datafile.1.json');

findCorrectAnswerCombination(allQuestionData);

function findCorrectAnswerCombination(allQuestionData) {
    console.log(ProcessNextQuestion(allQuestionData));
}

//This function will run all of the next questions
function ProcessNextQuestion(allQuestions, startingIndex = 0, dpObj = {}, questionNum = 1) {
    try{
        //create deep copy of Obj
        let copyDpObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dpObj))

        //Loop through all of the remaining questions
        for (let i = startingIndex; i < allQuestions.length; i++) {
            let question = allQuestions[i];

            for (let answerNum = 0; answerNum < question.potentialAnswers.length; answerNum++) {
                let answer = question.potentialAnswers[answerNum];

                //Determine if the current potential answer fits with the values already in the dpObj
                if (doesAnswerFitInCurrentDPObject(answer, copyDpObj)) {

                    //Add the new datapoints to the doObj if there are any new dps
                    let tempDPObj = addValuesToDpObj(answer, dpObj);

                    //if this is the final question then we have a valid path
                    if (questionNum === allQuestions.length) {
                        return tempDPObj;
                    } else {
                        //recurively run on remaining questions
                        return ProcessNextQuestion(allQuestions, i + 1, tempDPObj, questionNum + 1);
                    }
                }
            }    
        }
        return 'No matching values found'

    }catch(err){
        throw new Error(err)
    }

}

function doesAnswerFitInCurrentDPObject(answer, dpObj) {

    for (const condition of answer.conditions) {
        if (dpObj.hasOwnProperty(condition.datapoint) && dpObj[condition.datapoint] !== condition.assoicatedValue) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function addValuesToDpObj(answer, currentDpObj) {
    let copyObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(currentDpObj));

    for (const condition of answer.conditions) {
        copyObj[condition.datapoint] = condition.assoicatedValue;
    }

    return copyObj;
}
```

Comment: Why shall the desired outcome have `"Hospitalization": "never "` and not `"Hospitalization": "more than 2 years ago "` ? (I guess the space after "never" is a typo?)
From the text, is sounds more like you want to have `"Hospitalization": [...all possible answers...]` and an empty array could mean that there are no `assoicatedValue`?

Comment: `"Hospitalization":` should be never due to the fact that the second question object has two conditions, the second of which being Hospitalization. If the value was `"more than 2 years ago"` this would conflict the the only possible answer for the second question. I need each datapoints to have exactly one value as they represent individual field in an application where the `associatedValue` will be entered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually ended up finding the solution I was looking for, after much banging my head against the wall.

I was not handling the returning of values correctly. I needed to check after the recursion was called if the correct value was found. If it was I needed another return statement to end that loop. My loops would exist all the way back to the beginning in this case. Originally it would return regardless of whether or not the value was found.

```
//This function will run all of the next questions
function ProcessNextQuestion(allQuestions, startingIndex = 0, dpObj = {}, questionNum = 1) {
    try {
        //create deep copy of Obj
        let copyDpObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dpObj))

        //Loop through all of the remaining questions
        for (let i = startingIndex; i < allQuestions.length; i++) {
            let question = allQuestions[i];

            for (let answerNum = 0; answerNum < question.potentialAnswers.length; answerNum++) {
                let answer = question.potentialAnswers[answerNum];

                //Determine if the current potential answer fits with the values already in the dpObj
                if (doesAnswerFitInCurrentDPObject(answer, copyDpObj)) {

                    //Add the new datapoints to the doObj if there are any new dps
                    let tempDPObj = addValuesToDpObj(answer, dpObj);

                    //if this is the final question then we have a valid path
                    if (questionNum === allQuestions.length) {
                        return tempDPObj;
                    } else {

              //******************
              // This is what I needed to add
              //******************
                        //recurively run on remaining questions
                        let processingResultFound = ProcessNextQuestion(allQuestions, i + 1, tempDPObj, questionNum + 1);
                        if (processingResultFound !== 'No matching values found') {
                            return processingResultFound;
                        }
              //******************

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return 'No matching values found'

    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err)
    }
}
```